# Video chat with WebRTC on Android using PubNub's SDK and API

Tags: android, video-streaming, webrtc, pubnub

Hello I am attempting to implement Video chat between two android devices using the WebRTC implementation by PubNub by following this guide:

https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-tutorial

My code is very similar and am able to connect and have the video work both ways, however I can only here the audio from the caller on the callees phone and not the other way around. I have looked at the Logs from both devices and tried them both as the Caller and the Callee, the devices are a Galaxy S4 and a HTC One. I noticed that each time the Caller has some logging output (not from my code) that outputs "StartRecording" and "StopRecording" from the WebRtcAudioRecord class but the Callee never makes these outputs. Similarly the Callee outputs "StartPlayout" and "StopPlayout" form the WebRtcAudioTrack class but the Caller does not. I have included the exact log snippets below because the entire log is lengthy but I can provide it if you wish.

Caller:

```
D/AudioRecordJni: InitRecording@[tid=23807]
D/WebRtcAudioRecord: InitRecording(sampleRate=48000, channels=1)
D/WebRtcAudioRecord: byteBuffer.capacity: 960
D/AudioRecordJni: OnCacheDirectBufferAddress
D/AudioRecordJni: direct buffer capacity: 960
D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize: 3840
D/WebRtcAudioRecord: bufferSizeInBytes: 3840
D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AudioRecord session ID: 90, audio format: 2, channels: 1, sample rate: 48000
D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AcousticEchoCanceler.isAvailable: true
D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AcousticEchoCanceler name: Acoustic Echo Canceler, implementor: NXP Software Ltd., uuid: d6dbf400-93ce-11e0-bcd7-0002a5d5c51b
D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AcousticEchoCanceler.getEnabled: true
D/AudioRecordJni: frames_per_buffer: 480
D/AudioManager: IsCommunicationModeEnabled()
W/AudioDeviceTemplate: The application should use MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION audio mode!
D/AudioRecordJni: StartRecording@[tid=23807]
D/WebRtcAudioRecord: StartRecording
D/1077203.VideoChatActi: Debug Message from listener: {"packet":{"sdpMLineIndex":1,"sdpMid":"video","candidate":"candidate:1467089761 1 udp 1686052607 50.59.0.34 26520 typ srflx raddr 10.101.142.190 rport 56379 generation 0"},"id":"","number":"tomchtc"}
D/AICAction: AddIceCandidateAction
D/WebRtcAudioRecord: AudioRecordThread@[name=AudioRecordJavaThread, id=1857]
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/MediaCodecVideo: InitDecode.
```

and

```
D/AudioRecordJni: StopRecording@[tid=23807]
D/WebRtcAudioRecord: StopRecording
```

Callee:

```
D/AudioTrackJni: InitPlayout@[tid=9936]
D/WebRtcAudioTrack: InitPlayout(sampleRate=48000, channels=1)
D/WebRtcAudioTrack: byteBuffer.capacity: 960
D/AudioTrackJni: OnCacheDirectBufferAddress
D/AudioTrackJni: direct buffer capacity: 960
D/AudioTrackJni: frames_per_buffer: 480
D/WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize: 14336
D/AudioManager: IsCommunicationModeEnabled()
W/AudioDeviceTemplate: The application should use MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION audio mode!
D/AudioTrackJni: StartPlayout@[tid=9936]
D/WebRtcAudioTrack: StartPlayout
D/MediaCodecVideo: DecoderRelease request
D/WebRtcAudioTrack: AudioTrackThread@[name=AudioTrackJavaThread, id=2331]
```

and

```
D/AudioTrackJni: StopPlayout@[tid=9936]
D/WebRtcAudioTrack: StopPlayout
```

If anyone has run into this problem or has some insight as to why this is happening I would appreciate the help! if you would like any more information or code snippets I would gladly provide them.

Answer (score -1):

i made a minor bug fix and it worked for me .

all you need to do is set **OfferToReceiveAudio** true.

pcConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"));
in [PnSignalingParams](https://github.com/pushingthelimits/AndroidRTC/blob/b96b4e7d647ec393f394f4bb590162a8131021d2/pnwebrtc/src/main/java/me/kevingleason/pnwebrtc/PnSignalingParams.java)

which sets the user accepting call to receive audio as well.previously **OfferToReceiveAudio** it was set to false.

or

"For now you will have to clone the repo and add it to your project. Will rebuild artifacts for the gradle distribution shortly" - GleasonK.

[pull the updated repo](https://github.com/GleasonK/AndroidRTC/pull/14)